# MYSQL: Convert a list of ids to values in a subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery, string-interpolation

I'm trying to find a way to make my queries easier to read.

Say I have a table: with IDs, names, and partners.  Partners is a list of ids.

```
 - 0, john, null
 - 1, mike, "0,2"
 - 2, sarah, "0,1"
```

Is there a way I can do a subquery to show names instead of the partner ids?
select u.id, u.name, (select i.name from users i where i.id in u.parners) from users;

Something so I can get results like:

```
 - 0, john, null
 - 1, mike, "john,sarah"
 - 2, sarah, "john, mike"
```

I've tried something like what I've shown above, but I can't figure out anything special.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: No. See normalization.

Comment: Are you in a position to redesign this schema?  The list of ids should be normalized out into another table as a one-to-many `userid,partnerid`. As you have it, there's not good way to split them in SQL and join the other table. You would have to do it application-side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Normalization` is the best way for this. Otherwise, see `FIND_IN_SET()`

```
SELECT  a.ID,
        a.Name,
        GROUP_CONCAT(b.Name) Partners
FROM    tableName a
        LEFT JOIN tableName b
            ON FIND_IN_SET(b.id, a.partners)
GROUP   BY a.ID, a.Name
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3da81/3)

Suggested schema:

**UserList**

- ID (PK)
- Name
- other columns

**Partners**

- UserID (FK to UserList.ID)
- PartnerID  (FK to UserList.ID)

Answer (score 0):

It is better to follow [Normalization](http://ftp.nchu.edu.tw/MySQL/tech-resources/articles/intro-to-normalization.html) rules as this is a One to Many relationship.

I have created two tables here

1.users

```
create table users(
id int not null auto_increment,
name varchar(40) not null,
primary key(id)
);

insert into users( name)  values ('John'),('Mike'),('Sarah');

+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | John  |
|  2 | Mike  |
|  3 | Sarah |
+----+-------+
```

2.partners

```
create table users(
id int not null auto_increment,
name varchar(40) not null,
primary key(id)
);

insert into partners values (2,1),(2,3),(3,1),(3,2);

+---------+------------+
| user_id | partner_id |
+---------+------------+
|       2 |          1 |
|       3 |          1 |
|       3 |          2 |
|       2 |          3 |
+---------+------------+
```

You can use the following query to select  Users and their partner

```
select u.name Users, group_concat(u1.name) Partners from users u 
left join partners p on u.id = p.user_id
left join users u1 on p.partner_id = u1.id
group by Users;
```

Output:

```
+-------+------------+
| Users | Partners   |
+-------+------------+
| John  | NULL       |
| Mike  | John,Sarah |
| Sarah | John,Mike  |
+-------+------------+
```